# Identify PST timezone on non-english Windows installation

Tags: c++, windows, timezone

I am facing this weird problem where I need to fetch PST timezone information (e.g. MUI_Std, Std, TZI etc.) from Japanese Windows OS machine but unable to find a reliable way to do it.

I have tried RegLoadMUIStringW API. But it returns me name of PST timezone in localized format. I have PST timezone name in English with me. So using output of this API I am not able to compare and tell whether the value being read from registry is for PST timezone.

One possible solution is to have MUI_Std value of PST timezone in code (the value is @tzres.dll,-212) and compare this value with the values read from registry. This way I will come to know if the timezone I am reading is PST or not. But I am not sure if this is a reliable way to detect PST timezone.

Let me know if anyone has any inputs on this.

Comment: Congrats on your first question to stackoverflow, in order for other developers to provide answers, please can you post source code that illustrates what you have tried so far. Hope this is your first of many questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time zones are identified by their ID (aka "Key Name"), not their localized names.  The IDs are not localized.

Thus, regardless of language of the OS, you'll find the Pacific time zone information at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Pacific Standard Time
```

Of the values within, only the `Std`, `Dlt`, and `Display` values are localized, and the MUI values point to where those strings are located in the resource files.  The resource files are installed with the Windows language packs.  Note, you shouldn't hardcoded a value (eg, `-212`) because a future update might provide a new string that could change it.

Also, if you just need to retrieve the time zone information for a given ID, you don't actually need to access the registry at all.  Just use the [`EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-enumdynamictimezoneinformation) function to iterate over the time zones looking for the one that matches the desired `TimeZoneKeyName` (which again is not localized).

If however, you're looking for the localizations of these in languages *other than* the current OS language, you could try taking a look at the [TimeZoneWindowsResourceExtractor](https://github.com/tomkludy/TimeZoneWindowsResourceExtractor) project.

Comment: Thanks for confirming about Key Name. I think I can match the Key Name fetched from registry with the PST timezone name in English and that should solve the problem.

Comment: As long as you're matching key names to key names, that's fine.  But do be careful - not all of the key names are in the same format or would align to what you'd want to display to a user.

Comment: I am concerned only about PST keyname. Want to identify PST key from registry entries. So I think this should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a recent [SQL Shack article](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-update-the-t-sql-toolbox-database/) that shows how to extract time zone / time zone adjustment information directly from a Windows PC registry. The technique shows C# and VB.net desktop apps that build text files with time zone and time zone adjustment information. I placed the code at [my GitHub resource](https://github.com/fbsolo), and you can modify it if it does not specifically cover the exact data you need. Mr. Johnson-Pint's earlier content here at SO, and at his blog, really helped me build out my ideas.

HTH!